# Moola Nakshatra and Aslesha Nakshatra Myths

Tags: astrology, superstitions, birth, horoscopes

One who believes in horoscopes and especially during the time of match making, they strictly look into these factors before proceeding towards gana count and manglik.

It is said that Moola Nakshatra bride is not suppose to marry a groom who have Father and Aslesha Nakshatra bride is not suppose to marry if groom has Mother in South India.

Why, whats the reason? They say if they oppose and marry, then they will die and hence nobody takes chance. Is there any Significance behind this or its just a myth?

Comment: Ashlesha and Moola nakshatra are gand Mula Trikshana nakshatras requiring pooja for those born under it. https://qr.ae/TSbkC7 Not sure about harm on father-in-law and mother-in-law, but as per some astrologers people born in Ashlesha should be matched with ashlesha or compatible nakshatras, as they believe they have effect of Naga loka, as ruler of Ashlesha is Sheshnaag Ahi, resutling in death of partner if matched with person of any other nakshatra. https://qr.ae/TSbkdA